# What types of software can have "Hardcoded Password" vulnerability?

Tags: passwords, cwe, hardcoded

When I investigated the Google results, the software vulnerability "Hardcoded Password" (cwe-798 & cwe-259) is a vulnerability for IoT devices' software (see: [link1](https://www.networkworld.com/article/3332032/top-10-iot-vulnerabilities.html)) and thick client software (see: [link2](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/798.html), [link3](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/259.html)). When passwords are embedded in these two types of software, they can be revealed by decompiling them. Well, as an attacker this weakness can be exploited, because binary code of software is in our hand.

But what about web applications? I mean server side software. In web application software, as an attacker, the binary code is not in our hand. Because it is not client side software. It is server side software. So is hardcoded password vulnerability still a valid vulnerability for web application software? Or this vulnerability is just for IoT and thick client software?

Note: CWE web pages (cwe-798 and cwe-259) about this vulnerability just say it is an software vulnerability, but not say what type of software this vulnerability is valid for.

Comment: Are you including default passwords that ought to have been changed? One list of default passwords and the software affected has been compiled [here](https://cirt.net/passwords).

Comment: Actually I meant "finding out embedded default or custom password inside a software" vulnerability. Default Password lists are an another approach to find out passwords for various software. See CWE-1392 and CWE-1393 for default password vulnerabilties in cwe database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should expect that the attacker has the full application code.

Is your question maybe "How can attacker obtain the server side code?" There can be many ways for this. For instance:

- The attacker has got access to the build environment.
- The attacker has got access to the artifact repository where in particular the binaries are stored: GitHub Package Registry, JFrog Artifactory, Nexus Repository Manager.
- The attacker has got access to one of the staging environments, e.g. where the integration tests or where the load tests are running.

After the attacker has obtained the binary code, it does not matter where this code is intended to run, on the client or on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

Any application that uses passwords for anything can be affected by it. The MITRE CWE page that you link to gives several examples, including:

- Encryption keys.
- Default accounts.
- Hard-coded tokens and passwords that can't be changed.

All of these can apply to a web application just as much as a thick clients or any other kind of application (and many the IoT examples are actually affecting the web interfaces on the IoT devices).

They might be harder for an attacker to identify (as they may not have access to the application binaries or source code) - but that doesn't mean they don't exist.